# Pytorch super(class, self).__init__() vs super().__init__()

Tags: pytorch

So far out of all the paper and its corresponding code I see people use `super(class, self).__init__()` instead of `super().__init__()` within their def `__init__` function regardless of which python version people are using. Why? I thought they are the same thing but different syntax for different version of python. Am I paranoid or is there an actual reason to use the old format in pytorch?

Edited: It's for backward compatibility and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the underscore edited.

Comment: I never used pytorch. Perhaps the explicit version is backwards compatible? If comparing regular python2 to 3, the first one is backward compatible.

Comment: But since I never used Pytorch, I cannot post this as an answer but you could keep this as a hint to research further or try yourself.

Comment: Yea I am going to ask on their official forum as well thanks.

Comment: If you have an answer, please don't edit it into your question. Instead, post an answer in the answer section below and, if it's your own question, mark the answer as accepted. Right now the question shows up as "unanswered" and is bumped because you edited it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I got it, but I have to wait for tomorrow to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I asked on the official form and it seems to be just for backward compatibility and nothing else.